# Have other space capsule splashdowns attracted a crowd of civilians on boats?

Tags: spacex, history, water-landing

We saw on the SpaceX Demo 2 splashdown livestream that various clearly-non-mission-associated civilian boats appeared to approach the Crew Dragon within 100-300 ft. Has this happened on any previous water landings of spacecraft?

Comment: Apollo splashdowns were  far away from the costs, too far for those kind of various clearly-civilian boats. The same was true for Mercury and Gemini splashdowns.

Comment: From the After the Splashdown news conference (https://youtu.be/xdvuaiP6IoY): Gwynne Shotwell - "It's a large area to clear" ... "We'll need more Coast Guard assets [and NASA and SpaceX assets on the scene than we had today]"

Comment: A quick note on terminology: the "Go Navigator" recovery ship is very much a civilian vessel too. I'm many ways that's the whole point of the commercial crew program... ;-)

Comment: @user2705196 Ah yes. I’ll edit the question a bit.

Comment: @CourageousPotato it's totally clear what you meant! I just couldn't help a quip about the fact that the official recovery ship is no longer a US Navy aircraft carrier... ;-)

Comment: Another factor in this is the Go Navigator was / has been visible on public maritime tracking services. That kind of tracking was likely not available to the average mariner 45 years ago.

Comment: I hope that next time the US Navy positions a pair of destroyers nearby, and points their CIWS at any unauthorized vessels.

Comment: @IanKemp  that's impressively abusive and autocratic of you.  For one thing, the Coast Guard can do a much better job, with less risk of kill-crazy personnel going off.

Comment: It's "abusive and autocratic" to prioritise the safety of the astronauts and recovery crews over the safety of the idiots who choose to break the law and potentially endanger those personnel? Sorry, no.

Comment: Is "Go Navigator" an obscure reference to the "Instrumentality of Man"? I'm sure a reference to Neon Genesis Evangelion will come up at some point.

Comment: @IanKemp What "law" would that be? Those are international waters. The best you can do is "please be nice and stay clear". [Here](https://internationallaw.uslegal.com/the-law-of-the-seas/): "The high seas lie beyond the zones described above. The waters and airspace of this area are open to use by all countries, except for those activities prohibited by international law (e.g., the testing of nuclear weapons.)"

Comment: @DavidTonhofer The US Coast Guard can board any US-flagged vessel in international waters. https://www.uscg.mil/readings/Article/1548177/authorities/ "The Coast Guard may board any vessel subject to the jurisdiction of the United States, **whether on the high seas**, or on waters over which the United States has jurisdiction, to make inquiries, examinations, inspections, searches, seizures, and arrests for the prevention, detection, and suppression of violations of U.S. laws."

Comment: @DavidTonhofer See also https://www.uscg.mil/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=luZU9g1tNsc%3D&portalid=0. "This authority extends to any vessel over which the United States has jurisdiction. This essentially means **U.S. vessels anywhere outside the territorial waters of another country**, and foreign vessels in U.S. waters."

Comment: @ceejayoz so what is the actual law onlookers not interfering with recovery would be violating?

Comment: @eps Maritime law in international waters doesn’t really work like that. It’s more “We have jurisdiction over you, and if you don’t respect that, we have ways to force you to do what we want. If you still object, settle it through court or diplomacy.”

Comment: @CourageousPotato  apparently they lacked enforcement capabilities: "In a statement issued to CBS, the Coast Guard said it warned boaters multiple times ahead of the splashdown with radio alerts and physical warnings yet lacked an order to legally enforce a hazard zone."

Comment: so it would seem that really it was completely unexpected and they couldn't get the right general on the phone in time.

Comment: @eps The rest of the statement includes this, though: "While the Coast Guard has the legal authority to board vessels and enforce laws past the 12-mile navigable waterways rule, it would have required a massive undertaking of resources to engage each boat that came into the area and suspend the voyage or otherwise escort them out."

Comment: @eps As for what specific laws: https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/46/2302 "A person operating a vessel in a negligent manner or interfering with the safe operation of a vessel, so as to endanger the life, limb, or property of a person is liable to the United States Government for a civil penalty of not more than $5,000 in the case of a recreational vessel, or $25,000 in the case of any other vessel."

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No.

Most of the Apollo missions and some of the Mercury and Gemini missions [landed far out in the Pacific Ocean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Splashdown_2.png).  The rest of the Mercury and Gemini missions, plus Apollo 9, [landed far out in the Atlantic Ocean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Splashdown.png).  The mission that came closest to land was [Gemini 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemini_3), 110 km off Middle Caicos Island, and that was only because it missed the landing target by 84 km.

Also contributing to the lack of crowds is the fact that all prior missions were recovered by aircraft carriers, which tend to discourage civilian onlookers.

[Russia/the USSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_programme) and [China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shenzhou_program) have only ever landed spacecraft on solid surfaces, typically desert or steppe (or one [frozen lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_23)), which makes it hard for crowds of civilians on boats to show up.

Comment: Recovery used not a single ship, see https://history.nasa.gov/ships.html.

Comment: @Uwe, but the primary recovery ship was always an aircraft carrier (*Guam*, *Guadalcanal*, *New Orleans*, and *Okinawa* carried helicopters rather than airplanes), and the other ships were things like frigates and destroyers to <s>chase civilians off</s> provide security and related tasks.

Comment: What about other countries' space programs?  I know that some of the Russian capsules came down on land in Siberia (the occupants famously supplied with pistols and other cold-weather survival gear for protection until they could be picked up), but did they land any in the oceans as well?  Has the ESA or China or anyone else done an ocean recovery?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman China recovers on land. ESA hasn't flown a human thus far.

Comment: @ceejayoz *hasn’t flown a human on their own rockets. They borrow seats on U.S. (and Russian?) rockets.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman During the Demo-2 reentry a commentator mentionned that it was the first spashdown since the Apollo missions, except for one splashdown that a Soyuz capsule did in a frozen lake, unintentionally.

Comment: @FlorianF Okay, I was just making sure, because a lot of times, commentators (particularly in the US) make statements like that only thinking about NASA and not really considering other countries.